# $a,b,c>0$, prove: $\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}+\sqrt{bc}}}\le2$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove that:  $$\!\!\frac{a+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}+\sqrt{bc}}+ \frac{b+\sqrt{ca}}{\sqrt{(b+c)(b+a)}+\sqrt{ca}}+ \frac{c+\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{(c+a)(c+b)}+\sqrt{ab}}\le2$$

My approach using AM-GM: $\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}\ge2\sqrt[4]{a^2bc}$ ;  so we need to prove that: $$\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a+\sqrt{bc}}{2\sqrt[4]{a^2bc}+\sqrt{bc}}}\le2$$ Due to homogenious, I denote $abc=1$ which implies the new one variable inequality: $$\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}}{2\sqrt[4]{a}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}}}\le2$$
I am trying to find suitable term to finish my idea.

Is there any good way to full of my approach or other better idea? Thanks for help.

*Remark.* We have two ineqialities
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}\leq 1$$
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{bc}}{a+\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}\geq 1$$
Is there a relation here ?

Comment: For the final inequality, note that when $a > 7$, the expression is $ > 2$ so it is not true (EG $a = 7, b = 1, c = 1/7$.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing mistake. Have you had idea to solve it help me?

Comment: The estimate $\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)} \geqslant \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ca}$ using CS is stronger than the AM-GM you've used, but that already reverses the sign of the inequality as you may easily observe. So the AM-GM certainly leads to a reversed inequality as @CalvinLin mentions.  Perhaps the estimate $\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)} \geqslant a+\sqrt{bc}$, also using CS, could work - I will check later when there's more time.

Comment: Did a quick check for $(2, 1, 0)$ the second CS estimate above also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

We'll prove an isolated fudging$$\frac{a+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}+\sqrt{bc}}\le \frac{2a+b+c}{2(a+b+c)}.\tag{1}$$
By AM-GM inequality,
\begin{align*}
    &\frac{a+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}+\sqrt{bc}}\\&=\frac{(a+\sqrt{bc})(\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}-\sqrt{bc})}{a(a+b+c)}\\&=\frac{2(a+\sqrt{bc})\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}-2\sqrt{bc}(a+\sqrt{bc})}{2a(a+b+c)}\\&\le \frac{(a+\sqrt{bc})^2+(a^2+ab+bc+ca)-2\sqrt{bc}(a+\sqrt{bc})}{2a(a+b+c)}\\&=\frac{2a+b+c}{2(a+b+c)}.
\end{align*}
Take cyclic sum on $(1)$ we obtain the desired result. Equality holds iff $a=b=c>0.$

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative proof.*

We may use AM-GM as $$2\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}=2\sqrt{\frac{a^2+ab+bc+ca}{a+\sqrt{bc}}(a+\sqrt{bc})}\le \frac{a^2+ab+bc+ca}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+a+\sqrt{bc}$$
$$=\frac{a^2+ab+bc+ca}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+a-\sqrt{bc}+2\sqrt{bc}=\frac{a(2a+b+c)}{a+\sqrt{bc}}+2\sqrt{bc}.$$
It implies $$\frac{a(2a+b+c)}{a+\sqrt{bc}}\ge 2\left(\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}-\sqrt{bc}\right)=\frac{2(a+b+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}+\sqrt{bc}}.$$
Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}+\sqrt{bc}}\le \sum_{cyc}\frac{2a+b+c}{2(a+b+c)}=2$$and we are done!